# Need updating a document through MongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb

```
This is the Document

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e945816f935623478eb6cfc"), 
    "EmpID" : "00102", 
    "Name" : "Alanna Buggy", 
    "WeeklySalary" : "426", 
    "Holidays" : "25 days", 
    "Supervisor" : [
        {
            "Bonus" : "15.6%"
        }
    ], 
    "Trainee" : [
        {
            "Duration" : "Fully Trained"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the "bonus" in the "supervisor array but not having any luck, the code I am trying is

```
    db.Employee.updateOne(
{ "Name": "Alanna Buggy" },
{ $set:
{"Supervisor.0.Bonus": "22.5%}
})
```

and

```
    db.Employee.update(
{"Name" : "Alanna Buggy"},
{$set:
{"Supervisor.0.Bonus":22.5%"}
}})
```

anyone can help me with this <3 ?

Comment: Have you tried closing the quotes around `"22.5%"`? Just adding the closing quote on the first example (or the opening quote on the second example) results in a successful update for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is related with quotes

```
{"Supervisor.0.Bonus": "22.5%}
```

and

```
{"Supervisor.0.Bonus":22.5%"}
```

This sample works

```
db.getCollection('Employee').updateOne(
      {Name: "Alanna Buggy"},
      {$set: { "Supervisor.0.Bonus" : "22.5%" }}
   )
```